# Data Table cross label in rmarkdown

Tags: r, datatable, r-markdown, dt

When I call datatable in an r chunk in rmarkdown, the caption is labeled as a figure and I can only cross-reference it as a figure. e.g.

```
tab_data <- read.csv("localfile.csv")

tab_data %>%
  DT::datatable(arguments)
```

The caption will have a Figure label instead of Table. Is there a way to change the label to Table

Comment: What are your chunk options? (i.e. what is in ```{r}`?)

Comment: Appologies. I had it there but it didn't show. Lets keep it simple: just figureName for cross referencing and fig.caption.

Comment: You should set the caption using the caption argument in DT::datatable.

Comment: thanks Emily. The issue with DT::datatable is cross-referencing. I found that this a known issue. please see https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/313

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a known issue with no straight forward answer. see this for more discussion : https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/313